# how to Fetch Feeds from "Private" Twitter Account in Application

Tags: java, android, twitter, tweets

I am implementing an application which requires to fetch twitter feeds of the specific user.
I am getting the feeds from the Twitter API,

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

The problem is that I am not able to fetch tweets if the user is Private in Twitter account.
Public account tweets are accessible to me by using the below steps, but what about the private profiles?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

References:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-onlystatuses-user_timeline.html

Comment: Unless you're logged in as a user who has access to those private tweets, you can't see them no matter what you do. That's the point of them being private

Comment: I have also tried using logging in, and also fetching feeds but in the limited text of feed, but when I try to fetch "tweet_mode"="extended" it gives "Not Authorized" error.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing, I think; I'm an authorized user of a private feed, and I thought my applications on my twitter account would have the same 'permissions' or authorizations, but I guess not